# Magento2: Display popup when click Add to cart button

Tags: magento2

Hi I want to show a popup when a user click add to cart button. The popup allows user choose inventory. If product available in inventory selected, add product to cart. If not, throw the error message.

Please help me, How to do that? Thanks!